# WordPress menus lost when exporting local database and importing to server database

Tags: database, wordpress, import, export

I have a local WordPress site running on MySQL. I wanted to move it to a server for testing and deployment. In addition to migrating new/changed code and media files, I exported the database from my local machine to a .sql file using Sequel Pro on Mac. Then I changed all URLs in the export to match the URL of the server. Then I imported it to the server database.

Everything's fine. No errors. Except the menus I created on my local machine are not showing up on the server. I'm seeing recommendations for plugins to export menus and import them on the server. But that seems silly to me. Aren't menus defined in the database? Isn't *everything* defined there in terms of content, options, settings, etc.? Why would I need to export/import menus and nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I was using a Pantheon.io-based upload/import feature to upload and import my .sql file. When I instead used Sequel Pro on MacOS to export my local database, connect to and import it to Pantheon.io, everything came through.

Answer (score 0):

When you export and import the database of the wordpress site, the menus also include in it.

You just need to check in your admin panel the menu will be there. You just need to assign that menu for appropriate menu location like primary or which you have created, like this screenshot https://prnt.sc/1wp2gvd

Comment: Thanks. That was one of the first things I had thought as well, but when I went to choose the menus from the dropdown to assign, they weren't in the dropdown. Compare this screenshot of my local (https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/15270421?key=40730dadc54932b533fe835b830a2603) with this screenshot of my server (https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/15270471?key=85c63323be7343227dfb052771b096d7). This shouldn't happen with an all-tables .sql export/import of the entire DB, right?